# selenium server launching two test execution tabs in firefox

Tags: java, jsf, selenium, seam, htmlsuite

So as the title suggests, when launching my `HTML` suite with a custom firefox profile (also with `multiwindow`), the server is launching two tabs, both trying to execute the test, targetting the same single window the actions are being carried out in. If I close one of the selenium tabs, the test will then complete successfully.

The custom profile is a profile created in firefox 19.0.2 and I am now running it in 20.0

Now If I update up the custom profile to coincide with the latest version of firefox, this fixes the tab issue when launching the test...however my question is....

Does anybody know the cause of this behaviour?

Many thanks,

Joe

Comment: Sounds like you have enabled the setting to open 2 tabs when the browser starts.  You can disable that.

Answer (score 0):

I think Firefox opens the second tab because the current milestone of the browser software does not match the value of the setting `browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone` in prefs.js: The browser tries to show sort of a successful-update-page in a new tab.

According to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102313
you can suppress this behaviour by manually setting `browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone` to `ignore`. For me, this single change in prefs.js did the trick.

halfbit